# Android: Maybe FEATURE_PROGRESS cause app unfortunately stopped

Tags: android

I have problem with the code below

```
package com.example.ch13_searchflickrr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView wv;
String query = "";
String baseURL = "http://m.flickr.com/#/search/advanced/_QM_q_IS_";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
            setProgress(progress*100);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
            wv.canGoBack()){
        wv.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void search(View v){


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

While executing above code,
it'll show `unfortunately stopped`.

But if I remove the line:

> this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

then the application could run,
so, I think that the problem is here,
but, I don't know how to use that line correctly,
Can anyone give some advice?  Thanks!

Comment: the image: http://i.imgur.com/EUo1GeP.png?1

Comment: image 2: http://i.imgur.com/5LIlL8b.png
besides i use eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LogCat shows

> requestfeature must be called before adding content

To solve this,

`requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);` Must be called before  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

It should be:

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: the book i see say : "requestFeature should before setContentView"  but didn't say that it should before super.OnCreate, too, so the book i see has mistake here.  Thanks again !   (my badges are not enough to vote up QQ)